# Encoding ASCII changes right and left double quotes to question mark

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp-classic, mailmessage

So say we have this in body of an email message:

```
body =  “Hi John,  thank you”;
```

when encoding that into

```
Message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
```

the return is ?Hi John,  thank you?

how can I avoid this? I used other encodings from System Encoding but they do not resolve the problem.

Of course a work around would be to replace the right and left quotes with simple double quotes...

Can you tell me an alternative?

Comment: maybe this: Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

Comment: why would someone just down vote without a comment or a reason... I think my solution is Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

Comment: So you blindly went through the list of encodings hoping one would fix it? Do you understand what encodings are and why "fancy quotes" produce `?` in other encodings?

Comment: What encoding did you start with? Why are you trying to convert the encoding to ASCII? Why is [tag:asp-classic] included?

Comment: @Lankymart the right and left were pasted into a mail message textarea... Yes, I did blindly went through the different encoding as encoding is nothing but just a special format ...  If I knew why it is producing and knew the answer wouldn't have posted a question here?

Comment: Doesn't asp-classic deal with encoding?

Comment: Every programming language known to man will deal with encoding at some point, what's your point? How is asp-classic relevant to your specific question?

Comment: @Lankymart since this is an asp application and textarea in an asp app that posts the text.. ... In any case, thank you for your help..

Comment: Then you've made my point for me. Why does your question not include any or all of this information? I'm no mind reader or others here at SO to my knowledge.

Comment: One alternative is to use an encoder that throws exceptions instead of replacing characters. Even if you find what you think is the right encoding, you can extend the encoder to check your assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
```